# Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreanimated.so" not found, js engine: hermes

Tags: android, reactjs, native, react-native-reanimated

I am badly struck with below error and cannot find solution anywhere from last 3 days, I had recently upgraded to react native 0.72.3 and i think there is some problem with react-native-reanimated library.

Error is ---- Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreanimated.so" not found, js engine: hermes

Tried to install latest reanimated 3.4.2 version and also rolled back to previous version but nothing works,